# CSS centralising elements

Tags: css, flexbox, css-position

So I'm learning about css graphics and I'm trying to create this image in css:

[image]

I have started with flexbox to try and lay out my items but have since learnt I can't centre my circle in the centre. It's also not yet responsive. I haven't tried to centre the logo yet either. All elements need to keep their aspect ratio.

Can someone tell me where i'm going wrong please?

Once I've got the image centred too, I want to make the orange and blue boxes into buttons. I'd appreciate how to overlay a transparent button too if possible.

I have put my code on [codepen](https://codepen.io/BeyondBeta/pen/PVmNwW) and in a snippet below.

```css
*{
 color: #535252;
 font-family: --var(BB_font);
}

body {
 font-size: 15px;
 background-color: #c3c5c8;
}

.title{
 font-size: 5em
}

.image {
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
}

.orangeRectangle {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 
 border-top-right-radius: 150px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 150px;
 z-index: 0;

 background: #ec673e;
}

.blueRectangle {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;

 border-top-left-radius: 150px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 150px;
 z-index: 0;

 background: #67b9ce;
}

.rectangleTitle {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 3em
}

.greyCircle {
 width: 40%;
 height: 40%;
 position: absolute;
 left: 30%;
 top: 25%;
 align-self: center;
 z-index: 5;
 background-color: #535252;
 border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Landing Page</title>

 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700" rel="stylesheet">

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="BB1.css">
</head>
<body>



<div class="container pt-2">
 <div class="border border-dark d-flex flex-row justify-content-center">
  <h1 class="title">Header</h1>
 </div>
 <div class="border border-dark d-flex flex-row justify-content-center align-items-stretch" style="height: 950px">
  <div class="blueRectangle border-left border-bottom">
   <h2 class="rectangleTitle pt-2">Heading 1</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="orangeRectangle border-left border-bottom border-right">
   <h2 class="rectangleTitle pt-2">Heading 2</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="greyCircle"></div>
 </div>  
 <div class="border border-dark d-flex flex-row justify-content-center align-items-center" style="height: 150px">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam cum iste voluptatibus reprehenderit in dolor veritatis non eveniet at. Suscipit molestiae maxime laboriosam! Ipsa praesentium consectetur ratione quo distinctio iure nulla explicabo quas consequatur, id deserunt ducimus labore error vitae omnis animi facilis harum debitis. Facere architecto impedit eaque excepturi dolorum optio nemo ab! Iusto, vel non veritatis dolorem debitis voluptatum provident omnis commodi perspiciatis velit distinctio! Deleniti, nam aliquid quidem repudiandae voluptates, excepturi aperiam nesciunt quo ad officia impedit. Ipsa eveniet culpa ullam odio amet ea cupiditate consectetur et? Illo, accusamus tempore. Dolor voluptas voluptatum asperiores esse illo eaque.</p>
 </div>
</div>



    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Centering in Flexbox

With flexbox, the simplest trick for centering anything is to set the containing element to `display: flex;` or `display: inline-flex;` and then add `align-items: center;` (this will vertically center all content) and `justify-content: center` (this is for horizontal centering).

Like this:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.flex-container {
  border: 5px solid red;
  display: flex;
  height: calc(100vh - 10px);
  width: calc(100vw - 10px);
}

.center-everything {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container center-everything">
  <strong>center me!</strong>
</div>
```

## Maintaining Aspect Ratio

Regarding maintaining aspect ratio, you will want to define `height` and `width` for each element. If you need this layout to be responsive (aka, maintain all aspect ratios when sized up or down), you can use [relative units](https://thecssworkshop.com/lessons/relative-units) to ensure that your proportions are fixed.

## Making Elements Into Anchors or Buttons Via Wrapping

Making an element into a button is as easy as wrapping it in `<a></a>` or `<button></button>` tags, which are inline tags that should maintain your layout when used as wrappers. You can then customize the actions these links/buttons execute using `href`, `onclick`, or JavaScript event listeners (see my demo below). There's a plethora of resources online if you search for any of that.

## Overlaying and `position: absolute`

Regarding overlaying, you can easily create an overlay element by nesting it inside a container and then laying the nested element over that container using `position: absolute` (this breaks the element out of the [z-plane](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) and positions it relative to a container with `position: relative`). You can set the `height` and `width` to 100% since this nested element is now relative to its `position: relative` container, so these settings will ensure the element overlays the entire containing element. You can then position the element using `top: 0` and `left: 0`, which will ensure the element is flush with two sides of its container.

A good article on this: https://teamtreehouse.com/community/how-css-position-absolute-brings-the-overlay-element-to-the-front

See this demo with multiple overlays of semi-transparent colors, using `position: absolute` inside of a `position: relative` container (with some fun toggling action for kicks):

```js
const overlayYellow = document.querySelector(".overlay.yellow");
const overlayBlue = document.querySelector(".overlay.blue");
const buttonYellow = document.querySelector(".btn.yellow");
const buttonBlue = document.querySelector(".btn.blue");

buttonYellow.addEventListener('click', () => {
  toggleOverlay('yellow');
});

buttonBlue.addEventListener('click', () => {
  toggleOverlay('blue');
});

function toggleOverlay(color) {
  const overlay = (color === 'yellow') ? overlayYellow : overlayBlue;
  
  if (overlay.classList.contains('hidden')) {
    overlay.classList.remove('hidden');
  } else {
    overlay.classList.add('hidden');
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  background: red;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.overlay {
  display: block;
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
  left: 5px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  z-index: 1;
}

.overlay.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}

.overlay.blue {
  background: blue;
}

.overlay.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 36px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 12px;
  width: 180px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.btn.yellow {
  top: 12px;
}

.btn.blue {
  top: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="overlay yellow"></div>
  <div class="overlay blue"></div>
  <button class="btn yellow">Toggle yellow overlay!</button>
  <button class="btn blue">Toggle blue overlay!</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to approach this is to make an additional div container. Inside this container, you have your background and the logo with the grey background as a kind of an overlay. I updated your [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XORdpQ?editors=1100) accordingly.

```
.greyCircle {
    width: 40vh;
    height: 40vh;
    z-index: 5;
    background-color: #535252;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.circle-container-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  top: 0;
}

.additional-outer-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 950px
}
```

I recommend you having a look on [How to Center in CSS](http://howtocenterincss.com/) and [A Complete Guide to flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). These two sites are awesome resources, when it comes to creating layouts in css.